# How can I fix this problem in tensorflow.fit in Python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

can you tell me what the problem is with this code?
The last line of the code means

```
history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

there is a problem but I can not understand where the problem comes from

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import imdb
from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras import optimizers
from keras import losses
from keras import metrics
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

(train_data, train_labels), (test_data,test_labels) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

def vectorsize_sequeces(sequences, dimension=10000):
  results = np.zeros((len(sequences), dimension))
  for i, sequences in enumerate(sequences):
    results[i, sequences] = 1.
  return results

x_train = vectorsize_sequeces(train_data)
x_test = vectorsize_sequeces(test_data)

y_train = np.asarray(train_labels).astype('float32') 
y_test = np.asarray(test_labels).astype('float32')

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation='relu',input_shape=(10000,)))
model.add(layers.Dense(16,activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentopy',metrics=['accuracy'])

x_val = x_train[:10000]
partial_x_train = x_train[10000:]
y_val = y_train[:10000]
partial_y_train = y_train[10000:]

history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

The errors we have

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-be6266211430> in <module>()
----> 1 history = model.fit(partial_x_train, partial_y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=512, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1127           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1128             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1129               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1130             else:
   1131               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 878, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 867, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 810, in train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 184, in __call__
        self.build(y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 133, in build
        self._losses = tf.nest.map_structure(self._get_loss_object, self._losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 273, in _get_loss_object
        loss = losses_mod.get(loss)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2134, in get
        return deserialize(identifier)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 2093, in deserialize
        printable_module_name='loss function')
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 709, in deserialize_keras_object
        f'Unknown {printable_module_name}: {object_name}. Please ensure '

    ValueError: Unknown loss function: binary_crossentopy. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad spelling mistake on

> binary_crossentropy

you wrote:

> binary_crossentopy

Use this:

```
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[tf.keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/binary_crossentropy)